# pyspark reduce by key not giving proper value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have few key value pair in a text file in comma-separated fashion like (1,23) (2,25) (1,45) etc. here 1 is the key and 23 is the value. Now in spark i am doing reduce by key operation

```
entries = sc.textFile("scala/test.txt")
sum = textFile.map(lambda entry : (entry.split(',')[0]), entry.split(',')[1] )).reduceByKey(lambda val1,val2 : val1 + " " +val2)
```

the output i am getting as

```
(u'1', u'23  45')
```

where u'1'' is the key and  u'23  45' are values supposed to be added.
This I can understand because here key value both are string after splitting so basically both values are being concatenated.

but if I want to get them as integer I am doing

```
sum = textFile.map(lambda entry : (int(entry.split(',')[0])), int(entry.split(',')[1] ))).reduceByKey(lambda val1,val2 : val1 + val2)
```

but here I am getting error. please help me how get rid of this u' strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using: encode('utf8') to getrid of u'

input:

```
[ramisetty@dragon1 vijay]$ cat test.txt
1,23
2,25
1,45
```

$SPARK_HOME/bin/pyspark

```
>>>entries = sc.textFile("/home/ramisetty/vijay/test.txt")
>>>sum = entries.map(lambda entry : (entry.split(',')[0].encode('utf8'), entry.split(',')[1].encode('utf8'))).reduceByKey(lambda val1,val2 : int(val1)+int(val2))
>>> sum.collect()
```

**result:**

[('2', '25'), ('1', 68)]